# AlwaysOn Availability Groups and Encrypted Channels

Tags: sql-server

If I want to implement both AlwaysOn Availability Groups and Encrypted Channels, how would I do this?

There is a desktop application (Visual Studio 2008 built) that interacts with this database, and the client wants traffic between the application and the database encrypted.  They also want redundancy in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply enable SSL on each replica as per normal, but the certificate you provision should have a CN that matches the Listener name that you're connecting to.

[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#certificate-requirements) for more info.

Comment: Would I need to modify the application at all, or just connect to the listener?

Comment: Your connection strings need to be updated to encrypt the connection, or you need to configure "Force Encryption" at the server end, or both. Its a good idea to put the encrypt option in your connection strings but if you have force encryption enabled it should force them to use SSL anyway.

Comment: Thank you.  The connection strings are implemented via a config file, so that's easy.

Comment: And now I've tried.  Each replica's certificate has a CN of that server's FQDN, and an SAN of the listener's FQDN.  The certificate store on my test client has all four certificates installed, and the config file says Encrypt=True; and TrustServerCertificate=True in the proper place.  

Now, when the VS 2008 app starts up, it errors out.  I'm not sure where to start looking.